# Memory footprint when app goes to the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, instruments

In my app, the user can choose to display any number of objects onto the screen. Each one which is displayed has to be unarchived from a file, brought into memory, and then displayed. Usually, my app's total memory consumption rises to about 15 MB if the maximum number of objects allowed are displayed. If I press the home button and pause the app and then return to the app, the memory consumed drops to about 6 MB! Everything is still functional; the objects are still in memory. How is this possible? I am testing this on a real device. Is this a problem with Instruments or is there some kind of caching going on with a navigation controller that gets freed when the app goes to the background? Anything that would shed some light on this would be welcomed.

Edit:

I'm just now realizing the difference in the two 'Allocations' tools in Instruments. When you profile an app, you can choose 'Leaks' or 'Allocations.' By choosing leaks, I can see one measure of my memory footprint, which peaks at around 20 MB. By choosing allocations, I see another measure of my memory footprint, which peaks at a monstrous 230 MB! Obviously there is some difference in what each is measuring; which should I watch? I've always looked at the 'Leaks' allocation measurement.

---

Here are two recent profiles taken at the same point in the app:

With 'Leaks' I got this result:

[image: Leaks]

With 'Allocations' I got this result:

[image: Allocations]

Can somebody explain to me the meaning behind this difference?

Comment: I'm guessing that some code / data used during setup gets freeze-dried when you go into the background, and never gets used again later.

Comment: Some code / data.... 9 megs of code / data?

Comment: Which number are you using for the amount of memory?  Wired?  Dirty?

Comment: I'm talking about the number of overall bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, allocation shows you the amount of memory allocated in total but does not get rid of the bits that were deallocated. Leaks shows you the amount of memory that was leaked, in other words which was allocated but not released. You must aim for this to be zero at all times. To avoid memory leaks either use ARC in your project or make sure your *retain* and *release* everything properly.

If you want to measure the amount of memory consumed by your app I would select the Activity Monitor in Instruments and that should show you the actual amount.